# Is there need to map ContainerIPDU to frame in arxml

Tags: autosar

Is there a need to map Container I PDU to frame?.

Also is it require to create IPDUTriggering for ContainerIPDU on any Physical Channel.

Is it necessary that all refer PDUTriggerings in ContainerIPDU are from same Physical Channel?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, yes, no :)

As `ContainerIPdu` is just a specific kind of `IPdu`, it needs to be mapped to a `Frame` if the underlying `CommunicationCluster` requires a mapping to `Frame`s (which is not the case for Ethernet).

For the same reason, a `PduTriggering` that refers to the `ContainerIPdu` needs to be aggregated by all `PhysicalChannel`s on which the `ContainerIPdu` is supposed to be transmitted.

It is not required that the `PduTriggering`s that refer to the contained `IPdu`s of a `ContainerIPdu` belong to the same `PhysicalChannel` that owns the `PduTriggering` that refers to the `ContainerIPdu` itself. But for the actual transport of a contained `IPdu` on a given `PhysicalChannel` the latter needs to own `PduTriggering`s that refer to the respective contained `IPdu`s.

Comment: can you suggest me what i can do to understand details like i ask in question?. I am reading documents you suggested in many stackoverflow answers.But by reading those i never get proper understanding of concept like this. @Uwe Honekamp

Comment: The first two entry points here might be the AUTOSAR_EXP_LayeredSoftwareArchitecture.pdf as a general architecture and concepts overview and the AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.pdf specifically for the SystemDescription you're trying to create here. In the SystemTemplate TPS especially ch. 3 (Topology) and ch. 6 (Communication). Here you'll also find certain chapter about differences between the needs of certain CommunicationCluster types, e.g. Eth w/ TcpIp vs non-TcpIp protocol directly on top of EthIf which might need a FrameMapping. And ch. 8 in case of Gateway and routing relations and mappings

Comment: Thanks for replay @kesselhaus . I found AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate.pdf very useful. But some time information is not sufficient.It create many question like i ask and then i don't understand how i can find answer for those

Comment: The best and most efficient approach to get the answers you need is to book a coach or a training, e.g. from one of the stack vendors.

Comment: @UweHonekamp: I copy that, and personally would say, Vector has good trainings. They also have some webinars.

Comment: @HarshaJumde: Yes, I know, sometimes have the same feeling, but in the end, it is usually the time factor while "running through the templates", that keeps one from understanding, because who reads and understands the material at once :) .. But with the time, it sinks in. It's also usually good, to try it out with a proper tool (from hand to brain) and hope the tool has good and proper validation rules checks in place. Some rules are not in the XSD schema but have to be implemented separately! (constraints in the TPS's)